# Вопрос начинается словами "как ты думаешь". Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, двоеточие, вопрос

Идет диалог, и один человек спрашивает другого:

— Как ты думаешь? Дети с кого берут пример: с друзей ли своих или с родителей?

- Возможный вариант. Как ты думаешь: дети с кого берут пример? С друзей ли своих или с родителей? Просто, если *как ты думаешь?* сделать отдельным предложением, то получается неопределенный вопрос: думаешь вообще. Непонятно, о чем спрашивают.
- Как лучше (как еще можно) расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно слова "как ты думаешь" в подобных предложениях отделяются запятой.

> Как ты думаешь, мы ещё увидимся? [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)]
>
> Как ты думаешь, могло там быть ещё килограмм десять? [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)]

**Как ты думаешь, дети с кого берут пример: с друзей ли своих или с родителей?**

Дополнение.

> Запятая перед «или» не ставится, если «ли/ль… или» соединяют однородные члены предложения («ли/ль… или» в данном случае не образуют повторяющегося союза).
>   Чувствительные дамы ахали от ужаса; мужчины бились об заклад, кого родит графиня: белого ли или черного ребенка. А. Пушкин, Арап Петра Великого. От света ли электричества или от волнения она слегка порозовела и кажется моложе. Л. Андреев, Христиане. 
>   ([Справочник по пунктуации](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392))